# magento contact form email is not received.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am using magento 1.7, I have problem with the contact form of it.
When I submit contact form it show successfully submited but email is not received to my mail address set in config.

Comment: configure your mail system on the Magento server to use a well configured mail server for example of your ISP
use an extension - AShroder's SMTP Pro module would fit

Comment: Please check, is other mail sending function is working on server or not ?

Comment: yes normal php mail function is working properly I have checked that.

Answer (score 4):

1-First, please check:  **System > Configuration > Contacts** , there **Email Options**.

2-Next, go to **\app\design\frontend\default\sm_theme\template\contacts\form.phtml** and find:

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

=> change to:

```
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>contacts/index/post/" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

If your site uses  **https://**
Replace the above form tag with:-

```
<?php
   $url = Mage::getUrl();
   if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']))
   {
    $url = str_replace ('http://', 'https://', $url);
   }
?>
<form action="<?php echo Mage::getUrl(); ?>contacts/index/post/" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

This would be help.
Thanks

Comment: This answer seems correct to me.
I also had to migrate my site from HTTP to HTTPS and the contact form action was NOT in HTTPS.
@Sumith : However, there is a mistake in the LAST code line, Mage::getUrl() should be replaced with the previous $url variable, previously constructed with/without the https string inside

Comment: its giving me 404 error on submit, if i use this code. can you help?

Comment: @Gaurav this is for magento 1.9 I have tested. Could you please clear the magento cache and browser cache? Also check if exist the contact folder in the theme and magento core.

Answer (score 2):

need to config. our sender mail address and receiver  mail address
 sender mail address  as your Magento store address

> goto admin side(backend) system->configuration
>   in general tab on leftend side ...
>   store email address ->custom Email 2 
>   set sender address name
>   sender email address(ex. XXXXXXXX@gmail.com)
>    now goto  system->configuration->general tab-> contacts > now here set your send to mail means receiver mail address 
>   reciver mail address (EX.XXXXXX@gmail.com)
>    drop_down_list select customer Email 2
>   email template Contact form(default template from local) 
>   save this config. now u can send a email form contact us page